# Apparecchio Vs Apparecchiatura

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice

Sto realizzando un software dove ho una sezione per la gestione delle apparecchiature.

Vorrei sapere come nominare la scheda di dettaglio:

Io pensavo al termine `apparecchiatura` mentre un mio collega mi consigliava `apparecchio`.

Cercando il termine `Apparecchiatura` su [**Treccani**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apparecchiatura/) si evince come:

> Nell’uso corrente, il termine è talora usato semplicem. come sinon. di apparecchio.

Vorrei sapere, a questo punto, se posso basarmi solo sull'uso corrente, o se lo stesso possa sottendere ad un errore di termine

A completamento del contesto, le apparecchiature che vengono trattate nel software non si riferiscono ad una sola tipologia di attività all'interno di una azienda ma le stesse sono eterogenee.

Comment: Sicuro che non sia meglio *dispositivi*?

Comment: @N74: Ciao, purtroppo, come ho anche commetnato nella risposta di DaG sono legato a termini di una normativa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se stai parlando di singoli apparecchi, fossi in te preferirei di gran lunga appunto “apparecchi” (o “apparecchio” a seconda di come è impostato il contesto), evitando “apparecchiatura”, 1) perché il suo significato primario, come hai visto, è quello di complesso di impianti etc., un po' come “letteratura” rispetto a “lettere” (nel senso di “belle lettere”) o “alberatura” rispetto ai singoli alberi e 2) perché fa parte di quelle parole che possono suonare inutilmente ricercate solo per il fatto di avere qualche sillaba in più, come “annualità” al posto di “anno”, “modalità” per “modo”, “tematica” al posto di “tema” etc.

Comment: Apprezzo il tuo punto di vista, purtroppo sto rispettando come termine principale, quello fornito da una normativa, alla quale devo necessariamente aderire (e le normative pullulano di sillabe inutili!) Quindi direi che ogni qualvolta ho una istanza singola, parlerò di Apparecchio, la voce di menu (ad esempio) si chiamerà "Gestione apparecchiature"